# Azure Service Bus security when at rest

Tags: security, azure, azureservicebus

I know that Azure Service Bus is secure while in transit because of SSL, but I'm unable to find any information about if it's encrypted while at rest.

If the content of the message is sensitive in nature, can Azure be relied on to keep messages private while within the Azure infrastructure - or should we implement message security?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of 4/25/2018, the page that @tyler-pollack referenced, has been updated to specify that encryption at rest is provided at all tiers.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-encryption-atrest

You can see the update in this github commit: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/commit/66214db8a21eefcece6441ae566041b90b2615fa#diff-f55bddd3fba462832c4a2d0e7918f750

Comment: I have changed the accepted answer to this since it is now the most current.

Comment: Are there any definitive references to the encryption algorithm/key size used by Azure to encrypt service bus messages?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to encrypt the data yourself.  There are currently no facilities built into the service bus for data at rest.

Answer (score 1):

Service Bus Premium currently supports encryption at rest - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-encryption-atrest#azure-resource-providers-encryption-model-support

Comment: Hey Tyler! When providing answers with links remember to give some context to help fellow users understand how it is relevant and how it answers the question. You can do this by expanding on information or quoting from the linked page. This also helps in cases where links become unreachable. See [answer] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to the currently accepted answer, currently in 2024 the encryption of data at rest for Azure Service Bus is limited to the Premium tier only:

> Azure Service Bus Premium provides encryption of data at rest with Azure Storage Service Encryption (Azure SSE). Service Bus Premium uses Azure Storage to store the data. All the data that's stored with Azure Storage is encrypted using Microsoft-managed keys.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-premium-messaging

Also referenced in this [Microsoft Q&A][1]:

> @Antra Sharma Azure service bus REST Encryption are only supported in
> Premium namespace and it cannot be enabled for standard tier Service
> Bus namespaces. As premium namespace uses Azure Storage to store the
> data therefor it provides encryption data at rest with Azure Storage
> Service Encryption (Azure SSE).

[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/424372/azure-service-bus-encryption-at-rest-transit-(stan